# Multiple object of a class in HashMaps

Tags: java, class, object, hashmap

I have a problem creating objects of class B, all objects should be separate. But when I make a change to one of the objects, all objects make the same change. How should this be practiced? This is an example code:

**CLASS A:**

```
public class A {

    private static HashMap<String, B> map = new HashMap<String, B>();
        public void newObject (String name) {
            if (map.containsKey(name)) {

        } else {
            Person person = new Person (name);

            map.put(name, person);

        }
    }

    //This method gets called several times, to create several objects

    //But it everytime i create a new object, all the old/existing objects change too.


}
```

**CLASS Person:**

```
public class Person {
    private static String name;

    public Person (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

}

Comment: Do you add multiple objects with the same name? If so: [a `HashMap` will override old `value`s if a new `value` with an already existing `key` is given](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-).

Comment: No all names are different.

Comment: can you also show the code that actually calls this multiple times ?

Comment: In this case, provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is it possible the `name` is being stored in a `static` field in the actual program? If so, all instances of `B` have the same name.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan that is abselutely true. This will solve my problem

Comment: Check `map.Size()` if its value is 1 then you are using same string.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan if you answer the question I will approve the answer.

Comment: @Peter This illustrates why you should copy-paste an MCVE that demonstrates the problem, rather than retyping code snippets. My comment was only an educated guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `name` within `Person` from being static to just being private (making it a member variable).